# I am building a small web application and i want to use JSON API to bring in Wordpress posts into my web app

Tags: php, json, wordpress

So I am building a small web app. I have set it all up on Ubuntu and I am using Wordpress. I want to use a plug-in called `JSON API` to pull in content from my Wordpress blog in an easy to read form and I want this to be updated to say have only 5 posts at a time being the 5 most recent ones. I’ve looked around and I was wondering if someone could help me and give me an idea on how to go about this? I am a complete beginner I have no previous experience I have not started typing any codes or anything like that because I'm not sure how to start it.

Comment: I haven't tried anything that is  what I'm saying I have no idea where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here, and which one you choose really depends on what works for you.

1. WordPress has a built-in API, but this is not a JSON API, it's XML-RPC.  It's pretty feature-rich and won't require you to write any code (on the WP side) to pull posts.  More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support
2. Read directly from the database.  This is probably a faster implementation if you're reading from the same box.  Simply connect to the database WordPress uses and query the posts table directly.
3. Find a JSON API plugin that suits your needs.  It's difficult to recommend any as you seem to have specific requirements.  Try some, and see what works for you.  The downside to this is you'll need to keep the plugin up-to-date, and you're using third-party code - I'll leave it up to you whether you believe that to be a bad thing or not.
4. Write your own!  It should be relatively straightforward to write a small script to pull in posts from the WordPress database and spit out a well-formed JSON feed.

Comment: When I say 'Small' I mean this is the first time I have ever done anything like this! I have no idea how to even go about writing my own, or in fact do any of what you said. I'm doing this as a work experience project and the one time I do need a little help I'm on my own is there any other web sites you could link me to on the use of JSON as this is the plug-in I have been told to use.

Comment: JSON isn't a plugin, it stands for JavaScript Object Notation - it's a really basic way of preparing data for transit.  You might be able to find a plugin to output posts in this format, such as [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/).  There appears to be a few available

Comment: I have had a look at a bunch of websites and I know I sound so silly but I still have no idea how to go about getting wordpress posts from wordpress onto another website which I have created. I really do apologise.

Comment: Is the second website WordPress, or something else?

Comment: The second website is currently a webapp on a local host server.

Comment: I guess what I'm really looking for is a website that will run me through roughly how I will do it if there is anything like that, or any examples of code that will help me.