# I have started building a small webapp and using JSON API on Wordpress to pull in wordpress posts onto my small webapp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

SO like I said I have got it to work so that the content is pulled in but as well as that i would like to have the date of when it was posted also.

```
<body style="background-color: white">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  var url = "http://wordpress.dev/?json=get_recent_posts";
  $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", null, function(posts) {
      post_content = '';
      for(i in posts.posts) {
          post = posts.posts[i];
          post_content = post_content + "<div class='blue'>" + post.content + "</div><hr />";
      }
      $(".result").append(post_content);
  });
});
</script>
```

So this is what I'm using at the moment and was wondering what would have to be done to get the dates to show up with the post also?

Comment: What JSON API is that? Is it provided by some plugin? (If it's [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/), it looks like the date will just be in `post.date`...)

Comment: Yes it is that one I'll give it ago.

Comment: Given your requirements so far, you might be better off using something that just reads the RSS feed from your WordPress site. There are plenty of jQuery plugins/methods for reading RSS, and that wouldn't need any plugins added to WordPress—your RSS feed is already there, built right into WordPress, in a very standard form, and gives you recent posts including their content and date... It's specifically designed to supply what it sounds like you need, in fact...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember speaking to you yesterday, here is the related post for anyone else: [I am building a small web application and i want to use JSON API to bring in Wordpress posts into my web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862049/i-am-building-a-small-web-application-and-i-want-to-use-json-api-to-bring-in-wor/24862182#24862182)

If you're using the recommended plugin you should be able to simply use `post.date` to get the post's date.  Your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  var url = "http://wordpress.dev/?json=get_recent_posts";
  $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", null, function(posts) {
      post_content = '';
      for(i in posts.posts) {
          post = posts.posts[i];
          post_content = post_content + "<div class='blue'>" + post.content + " - "+ post.date +"</div><hr />";
      }
      $(".result").append(post_content);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nice :) can you mark the answer as completed (the tick symbol) if that solved it please?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add the date to the output, so change the line to this:

```
post_content = post_content + "<div class='blue'><span class='date'>" + post.date + "</span>" + post.content + "</div><hr />";
```

You can also use other properties on the post-object, check out http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#1.3.-Responses to see what data is returned from the Service.